# how to remove some of the array keys in php

Tags: php, arrays

for example have such a array:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 4
    [DATE_CREATE] => 04.10.2013 20:47:52
    [NAME] => BCAA
    [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1
    [DESCRIPTION] => 
    [SEARCHABLE_CONTENT] => BCAA
    [CODE] => bcaa
    [DETAIL_PICTURE] =>
)
```

how to remove some of the array keys to eventually receive the following:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 4
    [DATE_CREATE] => 04.10.2013 20:47:52
    [NAME] => BCAA
    [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: He's not asking how they got removed, he _wants_ to remove them and is asking how to do it.

Comment: Won't `unset($arr['description']);` etc. do what you want?

Comment: How did you get the result array? Which keys are you trying to remove? (based on what condition?) Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define the keys to be removed, you may use this:

```
$array = array('foo' => 'bar', 'hello' => 'world', 'blue' => 'psyduck', 'abc' => 'def');
$reducedArray = array_diff_key($array, array_flip(array('blue', 'abc')));
```

If you want to define the keys to be kept, you may use this:

```
$array = array('foo' => 'bar', 'hello' => 'world', 'blue' => 'psyduck', 'abc' => 'def');
$reducedArray = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip(array('foo', 'hello')));
```

In both examples, the resulting array is:

```
var_dump($reducedArray);
// array(2) { ["foo"]=> string(3) "bar" ["hello"]=> string(5) "world" }
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `unset`:

```
unset($array['DESCRIPTION']);
unset($array['SEARCHABLE_CONTENT'];
... and so on
```

Comment: Hmmmm `unset($array['DESCRIPTION'], $array['SEARCHABLE_CONTENT'], ...)`. The same goes for `isset()`, it supports multiple variables as parameter :)

Answer (score 5):

Well, there is a function named [`array_diff_key()`](http://php.net/array_diff_key):

```
$result = array_diff_key(
    $array,
    [
        'DESCRIPTION' => 0,
        'SEARCHABLE_CONTENT' => 0,
        'CODE' => 0,
        'DETAIL_PICTURE' => 0
    ]
);
```

---

***UPDv1:***

There is a way, mentioned by **@BluePsyduck**:

```
$result = array_diff_key(
    $array,
    array_flip([ 'DESCRIPTION', 'SEARCHABLE_CONTENT', 'CODE', 'DETAIL_PICTURE' ])
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Make use of [**`array_slice`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) , You don't need to `unset` the keys here as you are assigning the array returned from your `array_slice()` directly to your same array.

```
<?php
$arr=Array
(
    'ID' => 4,
    'DATE_CREATE' => '04.10.2013 20:47:52',
    'NAME' => 'BCAA',
    'DEPTH_LEVEL' => 1,
    'DESCRIPTION' => NULL,
    'SEARCHABLE_CONTENT' => 'BCAA',
    'CODE' => 'bcaa',
    'DETAIL_PICTURE' => ''
);
$arr = array_slice($arr, 0, 4);

print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 4
    [DATE_CREATE] => 04.10.2013 20:47:52
    [NAME] => BCAA
    [DEPTH_LEVEL] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`unset()`](http://php.net/unset).

```
unset($array['SEARCHABLE_CONTENT']);
```

In this way unset the keys you don't need.

Answer (score 3):

Just use array_slice function, its perfect for this situation.

```
$sliced = array_slice($input, 0, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove from array some value by key  **just**:

```
  $someKey= array_search('someKey', $array);
    unset($array[$someKey]);
```

**Or just**:

```
 unset($array[$someKey])
```

For example :

```
unset($array['DESCRIPTION']);
unset($array['SEARCHABLE_CONTENT'];
```

**Or in your case**:

```
$result = array_slice($input, 0, 3);
```